# I have given all error which is shown in logcat

Tags: android

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.admin.employeetracker, PID: 10123
                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;
                      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:2)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6391)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.employeetracker-a-n6GpCl0bxZuc0hm6dgNg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.admin.employeetracker-a-n6GpCl0bxZuc0hm6dgNg==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:2) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6391) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Make a question out of it, if we don't know what you want we can't help...

Comment: Well as the logcat states ! The library you're looking for can't be found. I think you need to support all CPU architectures. Plus, we need more information to understand your problem

Comment: `ASAP` if you want something ASAP - pay for it. If you don;t want to pay - be patient, as your question is 0% more important than any other, therefore it won't be answered ASAP.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 1):

add this dependencies and try again

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:16.0.2'
```

check for latest versions by the way
and also delete all other play-services dependencies the second one covers them all

wish it would work